# Android 2.0 : Support Actionbar library (appcompat v7 support library without resources):No resource found @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I followed the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html link for implementing ActionBar in Android 2.0

I have followed the following procedures.

**i) Create a new Project**

**ii) Create a libs folder in my project**

**iii)include android-support-v13.jar & android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files and add them in build path**

My Manifiest  xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tgactionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tgactionbar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i got this error

**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value 
 '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar').**

Comment: Did you add action bat compat theme in manifest  for the activity??

Comment: @Maulik Sheth, No, what could i do?

Comment: See in your style.xml file, you need to add the style "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: @Sulfkain, how can i add  style "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in style.xml

Comment: <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style> This will override the "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" that is suppose will be on some library.

Comment: @Sulfkain, I put ur code in style.xml and got same error got in manifest. No resource found

Comment: sorry, the name from styles file is styles.xml with S final. Anyway you can delete the 'android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"' from Manifest, because it's seems you will not use this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using eclipse, adding the compatible library it's pretty easy:
[image]

I hope this resolve your problem.
Do a new project from scratch and try this, if doesn't work i will try other things.

Comment: Thanks,but I got this exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:51)

Comment: @Sridhar this kind of error are throw when some problem on the initializerm, don't seems to be related with Support Library, please, check all parameters are correct. If not, open other thread

Answer (score 1):

To add v7 appcompat library for action bar, then you need to add the library with resources:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download

Once you have included the **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar** and **android-support-v4.jar** files in the project build path, then you have to also add the Support Library Project. It can be found at

```
<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
```

To add the library project:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
2. In the Library pane, click Add.
3. Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
4. In the properties window, click OK.